# Singleton of List<Class>, is this even good practice?

Tags: c#

Would like to ask opinion on this piece of code:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string name, string details)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Details = details;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set;}
    public string Details { get; private set; }

    public static List<Person> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_person == null)
            {
                _person = new List<Person>(); 
            }

            return _person;
        }
    }

    public static void AddPerson(Person person)
    {
        if (Instance != null)
        {
            if (person != null)
            {
                Instance.Add(person);
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<Person> _person;
}
```

A singleton of List. It's more common to see a singleton of Class, just not sure if this is even good practice? Any opinion if this is normal/bad/good?

Comment: what is the purpose of this singleton when you allow the users to create as many instances as they want?

Comment: It's bad code, you should not use this way. So have a look at Implementing the Singleton Pattern for improving your code.

Comment: In addition to every other reason not to do this, the Instance getter is not thread safe.

Comment: @ArtYerkes that's something that I just learned today. Will continue reading on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Singleton is not really good to use in many cases, but IF you are going to use, try to isolate it and try not to use it directly

for example :-

```
public interface IPeopleRepository :  IEnumerable<Person>
    {
        void AddPerson(Person person);
    }

    public class Repository
    {
        // Singleton isolated to here...
       public static Repository Of { get; } =
            new Repository() { People = new PeopleRepsository()};

       public IPeopleRepository People { get; private set; }       
    }

    public class PeopleRepsository : IPeopleRepository
    {
        private List<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
        public IEnumerator<Person> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return People.GetEnumerator();
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
        public void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            if(person!= null) People.Add(person);
        }
    }


    public class Person
    {
        public Person(string name, string details)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Details = details;
        }

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Details { get; private set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Name} : {Details}";
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly IPeopleRepository _people;

        public Foo(IPeopleRepository people)
        {
            _people = people;
        }

        public void Bar()
        {
            _people.AddPerson(new Person("Foo", "Bar"));
            _people.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // you can get it here.
            Repository.Of.People.AddPerson(new Person("hi", "there"));

            // but instead of using it everywhere... inject it where you can
            var foo = new Foo(Repository.Of.People);
            foo.Bar();


        }        
    }
```

Comment: Holy this is very elaborate way of doing things, it's clean though. I'm marking this for the correct answer just because the idea of "isolate the singleton". I'll rework my solution. Thanks! :)

Comment: It's not too elaborate, your person class was a little confused as it was both a Person and trying to have a concept of a collection of people, so I separated it out,   I didn't technically need the interface... but it's super useful if you wanted to plug a SqlPeopleRepsository ( or use a depedency injection framework).   On top of that Foo is just throw away, and Repository is a tiny class to handle the globalness.

Comment: I don't have access to compiler now, but this part looks wrong: private List<Person> People { get; set; } = new List<Person>(); (unless MS has changed the code syntax in newer version? I'm a bit outdated)

Comment: It uses the newish syntax, yes

Answer (score 0):

Singleton pattern is to restrict creating another instance of the same object.
make small adjustments to the current code, to force everyone consuming your class use your 'AddPersons' method.

Just make your constructor private, so that no one can create a new object of your class.

Your method syntax will be something like

`public static void AddPerson(string name, string details){...}`